# Red icons appears in all drives Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons, dropbox

Today, in all my drives in Windows 7 appeared a red icon. I try to delete the IconCache.db but doesn't work.

[image: Drives with Red Icons in My Desktop]

Comment: Using regedit, what do you have in the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\DriveIcons`?

Comment: finally is a problem with the last stable version of Dropbox. The @Alex answers works for me.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1458973/1042707) which will also fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: it's caused by a change in the Windows system by the updates in combination with Dropbox. The Dropbox icon from folders is used on all devices. To fix it whithout deinstalling Dropbox I just removed the overlay icons (which I never bothered about):

Use the RegEdit to go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers

You will see a couple of "  DropboxExt0x" entries (01-10 for me). You can export a Backup from the whole "ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers" entry and then delete the Dropbox ones. After a restart the issue is fixed (for now).

Comment: If you could document the specific change to Windows I would be willing to offer a bounty on this answer.

Comment: This works prefectly! Thank you! @Alex