# All drives get red symbol when network drive connects (Windows 10 Explorer)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-explorer, icons

Since this morning it looks like this. Until the network drive X is connected (HiDrive Cloud) all drive icons look normal. Then they all get the red overlay icon, internal drives, external drives, whatever. I deleted icon cache and removed the HiDrive overlay icons as suggested here: [Red icons appears in all drives Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/1458228/red-icons-appears-in-all-drives-windows-7)

Anything else I could try? The network drive has been in use for a while and the app connecting it as such has not been updated. All drives including the network drive function perfectly.

[image: Screenshot showing Red X icon on all drives]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the latest version of Dropbox has casued this to occur. I had the same issue today, however once I uninstalled Dropbox, the icons reverted to their expected view. I also believe the previous version of Dropbox doesn't have this issue.

See linked thread for further information: [Windows 10 suddenly display "x" icon on all drives](https://superuser.com/questions/1458491/windows-10-suddenly-display-x-icon-on-all-drives?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As spookily as it appeared the problem vanished today. Maybe Dropbox has issued a fix, I did not do anything further and did not touch anything related to DB....