# Windows 10 suddenly display "x" icon on all drives

Tags: windows-10

This is suddenly happened yesterday (2019-07-10 UTC+7). I do not remember doing anything before this happened at my office PC, I do everything in my mind to solve this, including deleting icon cache, but none works.

Surprisingly when I am home, my home PC is also showing similar red cross when I start the PC.

The only thing I do to both PC is updating **Android Studio** a day before.

[image: Red icon]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Red icons appears in all drives Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/1458228/red-icons-appears-in-all-drives-windows-7)

Comment: Use the answer in my question [Red icons appears in all drives Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/1458228/red-icons-appears-in-all-drives-windows-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This happened yesterday (2019-07-11)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1458228/red-icons-appears-in-all-drives-windows-7/1458450#1458450) I do not remember doing anything before this happened at my office PC, I do everything in my mind to solve this, including deleting icon cache, but none works[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1458432/all-drives-get-red-symbol-when-network-drive-connects-windows-10-explorer)

Your Dropbox client was automatically updated to [77.3.125](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Desktop-client-builds/Beta-Build-77-3-125/td-p/354168) which is known to cause this problem.

> So from what I can see initially, @Disk4mat and @AKai-945 you’re both running a beta version of the desktop app, denoted by xxx.3.xxx. Would you mind downgrading to the latest stable version and let me know if you still see the same issue?

Source: [Bug: Fixed & Removable Drive Icons Have Red X Overlay](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Files-folders/Bug-Fixed-amp-Removable-Drive-Icons-Have-Red-X-Overlay/m-p/354269#M54421)

You should rollback to [76.4.126](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Desktop-client-builds/Stable-Build-76-4-126/td-p/354173) in order to solve your problem[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1458228/red-icons-appears-in-all-drives-windows-7)  I can confirm that the **DropBox 76.4.126 client does NOT** have this particular problem.  In order to avoid this problem in the future, you should perform the following actions, to prevent Early releases from being installed automatically.

> You can do this by going to your account settings page here, and
>   towards the bottom of the web page you need to toggle off the option
>   for “Early releases”.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the corrupted cached icons.db from C:/Users/(CurrentUser)/AppData/Local/ does solve my problem. 
Hope it solve others problem too.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the sync option. You don t have enough space on your one drive. Update your One drive space or disable the sync option.