# Cross icon near the local drive icon?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, icons

Recently I've brought a caddy for my Lenovo Ideapad 510 to fit in the HDD. Currently using Samsung SSD 850 EVO 240 GB for windows.

Just few days back, I'm starting to see weird icon near the drives in explorer.
And I've seen this problem after installing caddy. Even searched about it, but looks like no one is having similar problem as like me.

If somewhere have any idea, please do tell.
Thanks

[image: Corrupted drive icon lookalike.]

Comment: This has happened to a lot of people after the last Windows update. See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1458228/red-icons-appears-in-all-drives-windows-7 (that post is about Windows 7 but same thing applies to Windows 10). See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1458491/windows-10-suddenly-display-x-icon-on-all-drives?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Moreover, by deleting Icons.db from C:/Users/(CurrentUser)/AppData/Local/ will solve the problem.

Comment: You may want to add that as another answer on the target duplicate.

Comment: Already did that. Thanks for the heads up.